# regex fails to match simple string

Tags: c++, regex, gnu

GNU regex fails to match

```
string st = "ABCDAZEA";
cout<<"S:\t"<<st<<endl;
std::regex  expr("[A-Z]+", std::regex::extended );
std::smatch matches;
std::regex_search(st, matches, expr);
cout<<"found "<<matches.size()<<endl;
fflush (stdout);
```

what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: What is your compiler version ?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  I get 1 match here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b61a66974d6da11e

Comment: Shooting from the hip here (dunno std::regex) but my guess is that `matches` are the capture groups and you have none... What about `([A-Z]+)` as regex - does that work?

Comment: $ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least GCC 4.9 to use regex, I think.

Comment: thanks. I'll try 4.9